# High-harmonic generation and few-cycle lasers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser, non-linear-optics, laser-interaction

These two topics seem to go hand in hand:

- High-harmonic generation
- Few-cycle lasers

I've been searching the web for some time trying to understand the relationship between the two, but I can't find a clear answer.

Are few-cycle lasers used to generate high harmonics, or are they themselves generated by the high harmonics? (or neither?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be somewhat confusing, because the field uses two different kinds of short pulses.

- The first is few-cycle pulses in the infrared regime, which are used to drive the harmonic generation process. Most of the time these are in the Ti:Sa band around 800nm but ranging from 250nm to 4µm or more, and they are produced by a laser source, which typically undergoes at least one stage of chirped-pulse amplification along with pulse compression and other manipulations.

  In terms of length, the driving IR pulse can be up to several tens or even about a hundred cycles of the IR driver, though if you go longer than that you start to dilute the available power, and you risk saturating the ionization. On the short end of the scale, it is possible (but hard) to do pulse-length gating, where you produce an IR pulse that has only one cycle at full intensity, and therefore only one relevant harmonic-generation event. (However, there's normally easier gating schemes available.)
- The other pulse involved is the XUV radiation which is produced by the harmonic-generation process, i.e. the harmonics themselves. Because of the ionization-propagation-recollision burst-like nature of the HHG process, these are emitted as a series of bursts of XUV radiation, normally called an attosecond pulse train (APT). These are normally a multiple of the driving frequency, usually in the few-tens range (but going up to a few hundred or even several thousand if you work at it), and their durations are typically of the order of 250as, give or take, once you filter out the driver and the first few harmonics. Depending on the configuration, this can span from a few cycles of the XUV to quite a few.

  It's important to note that these are *not* laser pulses - they are up-converted radiation, so they're still coherent, but they are not produced by any lasing process, and you don't describe an APT source as a laser - you say it's an HHG source.

That about covers it, I think.